# Opening and controlling an external application from Python

Tags: python, pyautogui

## Hi all. I have a rather short question: How can I open an application inside Python ?

I've tried looking it up online and have seen solutions using **pyautogui**, **ctypes**, and similar libraries, but it doesn't work for me. I need the program to open literally inside Python, so that I would have full access exclusively to it, for example, so that a screenshot would be obtained of the program itself, and not the entire screen, and that would be when controlling the program, for example, when clicking on a particular button , it profited precisely in the program, without affecting other windows, so that it could work in the background. I want something similar to the actions of the **Selenium parsing library,** which allows you to perform any action in the *browser*, even in the background, *but "only in the browser" when I need to have this kind of access to the program*

I tried: Search. I expected to find

Comment: Selenium works because browsers expose their webdriver interface. I don't know of a general-purpose way to silently open any given application in its own background environment and control it solely from Python.

Comment: Maybe there is a way to create a separate process that will not be visible

Answer (score 1):

You can't run an application inside Python, as that's not what the Python interpreter is for.
You can only run Python programs in it, and from those access other programs on your computer.

Selenium is running a browser with a series of special flags and settings so to not show a full window but still render it. This is not usually possible with normal programs, especially if you don't tell us what program you're interested in.
Browsers are, for a series of reasons such as their headless versions, extensive SDKs and more, possible to integrate this way as a programmable machine. Selenium is also a quite large project and not simple to imitate

The libraries you referenced:

- `cytpes` is used to interface with functions, data structures and libraries from other languages, mainly C. Unless you have a lot of experience with reverse engineering or the source code of the target application, this is not a viable path
- `pyautogui` is perhaps your best bet. You can launch the target application via Python using [functions such as](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html?highlight=popen#os.popen) `os.popen()`, the use pyautogui to interact with the program.

Alternatives are program like [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/), which is extensively used to do this, or checking if the program supports command line arguments, which can then be automated via either Python or Bash/Shell or what you prefer.

Edit: you should give us more information about what program you want to run automatically. There could be a lot of specific problems or solutions

Comment: But, I still have a problem with the fact that it will intercept my control. I'm wondering if it's possible to do something like this using another process, so to speak, that will not be connected to my mouse and keyboard

Comment: @ACC Probably not, at least not without specific knowledge of the application you want to automate. Graphical applications are made and designed to appear on your screen and be interacted with visually. Only sometimes do they include direct interfaces that can be used "headless".

Comment: I you want that you could look into running the entire program inside a Virtual Machine or a Container to have a complete desktop environment and inputs separate from your main OS